# RUN apk update && apk upgrade ERROR unable to select packages: 4.708 chromium (no such package): 4.708 required by: world[chromium~72.0.3626.121]

Tags: docker-compose, alpine-package-keeper

I am trying to run the front end of an application I am working on.When I run this command:

`docker-compose -f admin-fe-compose.yaml up --build`

I get this error in the terminal:

```
 => CANCELED [pi-admin-fe build-env  2/12] RUN gem install sass && gem install compass                   4.7s
 => ERROR [pi-admin-fe stage-1  2/15] RUN apk update && apk upgrade &&     echo @edge http://nl.alpinel  4.7s
------                                                                                                        
 > [pi-admin-fe stage-1  2/15] RUN apk update && apk upgrade &&     echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community >> /etc/apk/repositories &&     echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main >> /etc/apk/repositories &&     apk add --no-cache       chromium@edge=~72.0.3626.121        nss@edge       freetype@edge       freetype-dev@edge       harfbuzz@edge       ca-certificates@edge       ttf-freefont@edge:          
....
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk update && apk upgrade &&     echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community >> /etc/apk/repositories &&     echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main >> /etc/apk/repositories &&     apk add --no-cache       chromium@edge=~72.0.3626.121        nss@edge       freetype@edge       freetype-dev@edge       harfbuzz@edge       ca-certificates@edge       ttf-freefont@edge" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Has anyone ever seen this?

I've tried using node versions, 10.20.1, 7.6.0 and 6.9.1. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling docker. I have Python downloaded.

Comment: Your dockerfile is wrong but you have not provided it.